# Titanium android keyboard deletes table title

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have the following code to create a table from the database:

```
    depAgregarButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        //dataBase('create', null),
        dataBase('insert', depNamesField.value );
        var databaseObj = new dataBase('query', null),
            data = []; 
        for(var i in databaseObj ){
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                title: databaseObj[i]
            });
            data.push(row);
        };
        table.data = data;
    });
```

It creates the table perfectly as desired:
[image]
But when I open the keyboard:
[image]
It deletes the titles from the table where the keyboard was over:
[image]

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`TableView.setData()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-setData) method or even better [`TableView.appendRow()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-appendRow).
Notice that you can pass whole array of new rows to `appendRow()` and call it only once - it will give you better performance.